# building simple kernel module mkmakefile: No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, makefile, kernel, kali-linux

I was compiling and building simple kernel module on linux

following is my Makefile

```
    obj-m    := hello-1.o
    KDIR    := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
    PWD    := $(shell pwd)

   default:
           $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

   clean:
            rm -rf *.o *.ko *.mod.* *.symvers *.order
```

when I run make command against the makefile I get error that **mkmakefile** missing

> make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.0-kali2-amd64'
>
> sh: 0: cannot open /usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.0-kali2-common/scripts/mkmakefile: No such file
> make[3]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.0-kali2-common/Makefile:552: outputmakefile] Error 2
> /usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.0-kali2-common/Makefile:691: include/config/auto.conf.cmd: No such file or directory
> make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.0-kali2-common/Makefile:710: include/config/auto.conf.cmd] Error 2
> make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.0-kali2-common/Makefile:185: __sub-make] Error 2
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.0-kali2-amd64'

```
enter code here
```

> make: *** [Makefile:6: default] Error 2

the from this page https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?46712-Kali-2020-1-VMWARE-installing-Alfa-AWUS036ACM

i changed my make file following line

```
   default:
           $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
```

Now it's giving different error that **auto.conf** is missing

> make -C /lib/modules/5.9.0-kali2-amd64/build M=/home/fawad/Desktop/infoFolder/Linux/KernelDevelopment/hell modules
> make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.0-kali2-amd64'
> ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
> include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
> Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.
> make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.0-kali2-common/Makefile:718: include/config/auto.conf] Error 1
> make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.0-kali2-common/Makefile:185: __sub-make] Error 2
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.0-kali2-amd64'
> make: *** [Makefile:6: default] Error 2

I found on internet I have to run `make prepare` command against Makefile in `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.0-kali2-common/Makefile`but now its again giving me an first error

> sh: 0: cannot open /usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.0-kali4-common/scripts/mkmakefile: No such file
> /usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.0-kali4-common/Makefile:691: include/config/auto.conf.cmd: No such file or directory
> make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.0-kali4-common/Makefile:710: include/config/auto.conf.cmd] Error 2
> make: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.0-kali4-common/Makefile:185: __sub-make] Error 2

I like to know how to configure make and linux so I can build external modules? like this one

```
    #include <linux/init.h>
    #include <linux/module.h>
    MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

    static int hello_init(void)
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello, world\n");
        return 0;
    }
    static void hello_exit(void)
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, cruel world\n");
    }
    module_init(hello_init);
    module_exit(hello_exit);
```

Comment: Please, do not use blockquote (citations) formatting for logs. Without preserved newlines it is difficult to read them. Use code formatting for logs.

Comment: I really dont know why it wasnt any clearer but my c file should have had same name as the `.o` I was specifying in kbuild file